# inset \footnote{} into header with xtable and tabular.environment

Tags: r, latex, xtable

Can I control the `add.to.row` command in `xtable` to place an `\footnote{}` in the `LaTeX` table output header?

This is how far I've gotten it. (I would like to find a solution using `xtable` and not `Hmisc')

```
require(xtable)
x <- matrix(rnorm(60), ncol = 10)
x.big <- xtable(x,label='tabbig', caption='Example of longtable')
names(x.big) <- LETTERS[1:10]
print(x.big,tabular.environment='longtable',floating=FALSE, 
      add.to.row = list(pos = list(seq(1,nrow(x.big), by = 2), 0, 1),
      command = c("\\rowcolor[gray]{.95} ", "\\hline \\endhead ", 
      "\\footnote{This is the first footnote that I would like to have 
      in the headder next to `I'.}") ) )
```

then I use the output in a small latex file. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\begin{document}
I
\vspace{100 mm}

% latex table generated in R 2.15.1 by xtable 1.7-0 package
% Sun Dec  2 15:38:26 2012
\begin{longtable}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J \\ 
  \hline \endhead  \hline
1 & 0.57 & -0.21 & 1.11 & 0.15 & -0.47 & 0.77 & 0.26 & 2.08 & 0.65 & -1.62 \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{.95}  \footnote{This is the first footnote that I would like to have in the headder next to `I'.}2 & -0.45 & -0.06 & 0.13 & 0.20 & 0.26 & 0.48 & 0.07 & 0.45 & -0.51 & 1.26 \\ 
  3 & -0.23 & -0.68 & 0.17 & -0.92 & -0.44 & -0.43 & -0.63 & 1.84 & 0.08 & 1.21 \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{.95} 4 & -1.60 & -0.69 & -0.11 & 2.12 & -0.12 & -1.81 & -1.51 & 0.67 & 0.22 & 0.43 \\ 
  5 & -0.26 & 0.14 & 0.86 & -0.78 & -2.04 & 1.17 & -1.48 & -0.38 & 0.80 & 1.49 \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{.95} 6 & -0.53 & -0.43 & -0.84 & 0.06 & -0.87 & 1.13 & -0.56 & 0.30 & -0.96 & 1.75 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\caption{'Example of longtable'}
\label{tabbig}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This produces this table,

[image: table01]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can't manipulate the header using the  **add.to.row argument**.

But why not to sanitize?

Here my solution : The idea is to put a tag in the header (**footnote** here) and to change it using sanitize option.

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(60), ncol = 10)
x.big <- xtable(x,label='tabbig', caption='Example of longtable')
names(x.big) <- LETTERS[1:10]
names(x.big)[9] <- paste('I','footnote')    # I put the tag on I letter 
print(x.big,tabular.environment='longtable',floating=FALSE,
      sanitize.text.function=function(str)gsub("footnote","\\footnote{my tricky footnote !!}",str,fixed=TRUE))
```

You can easily extend the solution to many footnots by using many tags.

[image]

### Update , case of multiple footnote

You can easily use thes ame trick for multiple notes, like this :

```
names(x.big)[1] <- paste('A','footnote1')    # I put the tag on A letter 
names(x.big)[9] <- paste('I','footnote2')    # I put the tag on I letter 
print(x.big,floating=FALSE,
      sanitize.text.function=function(str){
        str <- gsub("footnote1","\\footnote{my tricky footnote 1 !!}",str,fixed=TRUE)
        str <- gsub("footnote2","\\footnote{my tricky footnote 2 !!}",str,fixed=TRUE)
      }
        )
```

The idea is to assign the same string after the regular expression substitution.

Comment: Does anyone know a smart way to resolve the conflict between `\footnote{}` and `\endhead`?

Comment: @Eric it is better to ask a real question , isn't it?

Comment: you are right. Though I did solve it with `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` as described in the [longtable manual, p. 8](http://www.cs.brown.edu/system/software/latex/doc/longtable.pdf). Also, [described here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=558).

Comment: Great! This also works in Lyx. I pasted my lyx file there: [sanitizefootnote.lyx](https://gist.github.com/paul4forest/064c778714f6fff952be).

Comment: @agstudy How do you extend the solution to many footnotes? I tried using two sets of `gsub` functions in the `sanitize.text.function` but that didn't work.

Comment: @agstudy I just tried your solution with the sample code, and the footnotes don't actually appear. The footnote superscript numbers appear by the "A" and "I" in the table, but not the "my tricky footnote 1 !!" and "my tricky footnote 2 !!" text. Any thoughts? I can post a separate question if that's easier.

Comment: @agstudy I made a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813247/show-multiple-footnotes-in-xtable