# Show multiple footnotes in xtable

Tags: r, pdf, latex, xtable, footnotes

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675380/inset-footnote-into-header-with-xtable-and-tabular-environment) on showing footnotes in `xtable`, although the suggested updated solution isn't working for me. I presume this is because I am missing something in my own setup, hence the separate question. I don't think the issue is what is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422428/r-markdown-footnote-in-xtable), as I am using the `sanitize.text.function` in the `print` call rather than the `xtable` call.

Below is an image of the PDF output. As can be seen, the **actual footnote text** does not appear in the PDF output, even after rendering twice. The footnote superscripts **do** appear, however. I am rendering using the "Knit" button in RStudio.

How can I get the actual footnote text to show?

PDF output:

[image: PDF output]

My code from the `.Rmd` file is below.

````
---
title: "xtable footnotes"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        keep_tex: true
        fig_caption: true

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results = "asis"}
library(xtable)

x <- matrix(rnorm(60), ncol = 10)

x.big <- xtable(x,label = 'tabbig', caption = 'Example of xtable footnotes')
names(x.big) <- LETTERS[1:10]

names(x.big)[1] <- paste('A','footnote1')    # I put the tag on A letter 
names(x.big)[9] <- paste('I','footnote2')    # I put the tag on I letter 
print(x.big, 
      type = "latex",
      sanitize.text.function = function(str){
        str <- gsub("footnote1","\\footnote{my tricky footnote 1 !!}", str, fixed = TRUE)
        str <- gsub("footnote2","\\footnote{my tricky footnote 2 !!}", str, fixed = TRUE)
      }
        )
```
````

The `.tex` output for the table is as follows:

```
\% latex table generated in R 3.4.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package \% Tue Aug
22 09:45:33 2017

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & A \footnote{my tricky footnote 1 !!} & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I \footnote{my tricky footnote 2 !!} & J \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1.13 & -0.00 & -0.14 & 0.83 & 0.58 & -0.65 & -1.12 & -2.04 & -0.64 & 0.50 \\ 
  2 & 0.13 & -0.65 & -1.11 & 0.06 & -1.32 & -0.28 & 0.96 & 1.19 & -0.41 & -0.51 \\ 
  3 & -0.73 & 0.16 & -0.26 & -1.50 & -1.34 & 0.84 & -0.28 & -0.02 & -0.98 & 1.13 \\ 
  4 & 0.33 & 0.89 & -1.08 & -0.89 & 1.16 & 1.70 & -0.77 & -0.21 & 1.01 & 0.22 \\ 
  5 & 0.86 & 0.19 & -0.94 & -1.36 & -2.49 & 0.62 & 0.87 & -1.17 & -0.24 & 0.17 \\ 
  6 & 0.19 & -0.15 & 0.20 & -0.56 & 0.04 & 1.20 & -0.72 & -1.39 & -1.30 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Example of xtable footnotes} 
\label{tabbig}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix in the end, found through trial-and-error.

To make the footnotes appear, the `longtable` LaTeX package and environment need to be used. I added them into the `header-includes` part of the `YAML` header and then the code ran as expected.

Using the following code in the `.Rmd` file made the footnotes appear:

````
---
title: "xtable footnotes"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        keep_tex: true
        fig_caption: true
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{longtable}  

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results = "asis"}
library(xtable)

x <- matrix(rnorm(60), ncol = 10)

x.big <- xtable(x,label = 'tabbig', caption = 'Example of xtable footnotes')
names(x.big) <- LETTERS[1:10]

names(x.big)[1] <- paste('A','footnote1')
names(x.big)[9] <- paste('I','footnote2') 

# tabular.environment needs to be 'longtable'
# \usepackage{longtable} needs to be in the YAML header at the start of the .Rmd file

print(x.big,
      tabular.environment = 'longtable',
      floating = FALSE,
      sanitize.text.function = function(str){
        str <- gsub("footnote1","\\footnote{my tricky footnote 1 !!}", str, fixed = TRUE)
        str <- gsub("footnote2","\\footnote{my tricky footnote 2 !!}", str, fixed = TRUE)
    }
  )
```
````

The generated table looks like this, with footnotes at the bottom of the page:

[image: fixed table with footnotes]